# How to fetch title of page built using angularJs in java?

Tags: java, jsoup, title

Currently, I'm using a JSOUP connector to get the page title of a web page.
But if the website is built using angularJs, then JSOUP connector is not able to fetch the title because the title is not there in the page source.

```
try {
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948496").get();
    System.out.println(doc.title());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to get the title of the page if it built using angularJs using java?

Comment: Show us the code you have done to try and achieve this

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried to parse the angularjs.org using jsoup and it works just fine:

```
try {
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://angularjs.org/").get();
  Elements header = doc.select("title");
  System.out.println(header.html());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

gives me "AngularJS — Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework"

Could you please provide an example of a website that doesn't work?

**EDIT**: In [your particular case](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948496), the title is being filled in dynamically. So, the question is not "how to parse the angular website title", but "how to obtain the dynamically created title". I think that jsoup doesn't do it at all. It just lets you access the dom elements of the source of the webpage. What you want to do is execute the javascript and get the result. I'd look at some testing utilities (like Selenium) that use an actual browser to render a page and then obtain the elements of the final dom tree.

Comment: Please try above example with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948496